# What could cause a noise like a hammer on an A320 in flight?

Tags: airbus-a320, noise

Edited question:

I was on an A320, asleep, around the mid-point of the flight at about 30,000ft. I suddenly heard a constant noise like someone hitting the plane from outside with a hammer. The noise wasn't too loud but it was distinct. I looked around, none of the passengers seemed perturbed.

The noise continued for 10-15 minutes, stopped, then started again after another 30 minutes. I was about to bring it to the attention of the crew, but the plane had started its descent by then.

Does anyone know what the noise could have been? And should I have alerted the crew?

Edit: Checked the linked questions. Its not a PTU, because the noises were heard mid-flight not during take-off or landing. Also, the second part of the question, can be answered.

Comment: This could have been the PTU. See related questions [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/137/572) and [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11534/572).

Comment: Did you look outside to see who that idiot was ruining your sleep?

Comment: It wasn't [a colonial woman churning butter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABmTxZl4NK4) was it?

Comment: Problem: Noise coming from under instrument panel. Sounds like a midget pounding on something with a hammer. Solution: Took hammer away from midget.

Comment: We have a general question about [what issues passengers can look out for](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/170/1696), presumably a strange noise is something that the the crew would notice and not need passengers to tell them about.

Comment: @fooot When reading your proposal, [Radu094's avatar](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/419/radu094) popped into my mind. I just love it. Perhaps he was around… ;-)

Comment: The PTU isn't just used during take off or landing! It kicks in whenever the hydraulic lines need to balance out their pressure, no matter what phase of flight.

Comment: @JustSid Right. That's what the PTU is designed for (as I learned here :-)). But wouldn't it make the typical [“barking dog”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aGsXmNjPRw#t=0m25s) sound the A320 is famous for?

Comment: Don't worry, gremlins can't survive below FL 290.